# How to add a GoogleMap Search Box to My Maps?

Tags: html, velo

I'd like to add a search box to a map that I made using My Maps from Google, but I have little programming knowledge. It's for a student research that helps communities to understand urban laws. This is the link to my map: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1PoZCa2v0YpD_Ki9OvX4jVm-HByYWo9ok&usp=sharing and this is what I've found on the web: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview. Is there a way to add a search box so people can type locations and find out if they live inside the polygons? Thank you all in advance. This is my website: https://michaelafalves.wixsite.com/zeisjasalvador. It's not finished yet and it displays a search box, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Good day Michaela you will find how to do it in this link. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Answer (score 0):

If you include valid map key then this code will not give error. This is not my code this is google developed code.

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
function initAutocomplete() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: "roadmap",
  });
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
  const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  let markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
    const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach((marker) => {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach((place) => {
      if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      const icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
      };
      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(
        new google.maps.Marker({
          map,
          icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location,
        })
      );

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Places Search Box</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      id="pac-input"
      class="controls"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search Box"
    />
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places&v=weekly"
      async
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```